# Big number deserialisation throws NumberFormatException

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson, jackson-databind

I wrote below program to convert `Parameter` to `JsonNode`. Getting `NumberFormatException` when I set `3.9E38`. How to set `BigDecimal` in JsonNode?

```
public class JsonCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        Parameter p = new Parameter();
        p.setPrevValue(new BigDecimal("3.9E38"));
        JsonNode node =  om.convertValue(p,JsonNode.class);
        System.out.println(node);

    }
    public static class DefaultValueSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeNumber(o.toPlainString());
    }
}

    public static class Parameter {

        @JsonSerialize(using = DefaultValueSerializer.class)
        private BigDecimal prevValue;

        public void setPrevValue(BigDecimal prevValue) {
            this.prevValue = prevValue;
        }


        public BigDecimal getPrevValue() {
            return prevValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @michalk, Updated the code example. 
Need to convert the number in `non scientific` format. So using `o.toPlainString()`

Comment: You don't need a custom Jackson serializer for `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this because `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser` implementation used during deserialization (in your case conversion) process can not parse really big numbers. By default, number is treated as `Long` and value `3.9E38` exceeds it's range. Unfortunately, features [USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS) and [USE_BIG_INTEGER_FOR_INTS](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#USE_BIG_INTEGER_FOR_INTS) are not handled in this case and we need to write customization here. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.JsonParserDelegate;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parameter parameter = new Parameter();
        parameter.setPrevValue(new BigDecimal("3.9E38"));

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(JsonNode.class, new BigDecimalFirstJsonNodeDeserializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        JsonNode node = mapper.convertValue(parameter, JsonNode.class);
        System.out.println(node);
    }
}

class BigDecimalFirstJsonNodeDeserializer extends JsonNodeDeserializer {

    @Override
    public JsonNode deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return super.deserialize(new BigDecimalJsonParser(p), ctxt);
    }
}

class BigDecimalJsonParser extends JsonParserDelegate {

    public BigDecimalJsonParser(JsonParser parser) {
        super(parser);
    }

    @Override
    public NumberType getNumberType() {
        return NumberType.BIG_DECIMAL;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getDecimalValue() throws IOException {
        String value = getText();
        return new BigDecimal(value);
    }
}

class BigDecimalPlainStringJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeNumber(o.toPlainString());
    }
}

class Parameter {

    @JsonSerialize(using = BigDecimalPlainStringJsonSerializer.class)
    private BigDecimal prevValue;

    public void setPrevValue(BigDecimal prevValue) {
        this.prevValue = prevValue;
    }


    public BigDecimal getPrevValue() {
        return prevValue;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"prevValue":3.9E+38}
```